# What defines legitimacy of a DOI

Tags: journals, online-publication, doi

My coauthors and I recently published a paper on https://www.ijnrd.org/viewpaperforall?paper=IJNRD2307102.

The doi which was assigned to us is http://doi.one/10.1729/Journal.35162.

According to my knowledge doi.org is the sole provider of doi.

Were we scammed into registering for a unscrupulous journal?

Comment: The title question won't really help you answer the question of whether you got scammed (you did).

Comment: Yup, it's a predatory journal. You got scammed. For future reference -- https://libguides.library.arizona.edu/c.php?g=945334&p=6815520?

Comment: @Arno, I know India has a much higher number of people who publish in predatory journals, so if others around you think of them as legit, you're probably not going to notice the warning signs. However in this case I believe Abhitay is an undergraduate student who tried to publish an engineering project with his group (he and his co-authors lists their affiliations as B Tech at the university). A lot easier to miss the signs as an undergrad with little to no support from an established academic.

Comment: @Abhitay, if part of your fear is that you lost a chance to have your work published in an academic journal I can offer some good news to you, though it probably won't be what you want to hear. While I'm not in NLP (physics instead), the paper I read didn't read at the level of an academic paper. Instead it read as an implementation project performing a minor extension rather than something granting further deeper insight into the field (I saw no analysis of the literature nor the results). Basically, you'd need a lot more work to get published in a non-predatory journal.

Comment: If you are worried about potential impact in the future, you could try to convince your co-authors that the journal is predatory and agree to request they withdraw the paper. They probably won't (since its predatory and more papers looks better), but at least then if asked about it you can say you didn't know better as an undergrad and have asked for it to be withdrawn. That would probably lead to it being ignored in future evaluations when you apply for positions. If your co-authors don't agree (they may have other motivations than academic) then you can ask academia SE how to navigate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DOIs are unique identifiers governed by an international standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). They are of the form `doi:10.1109/5.771073` (often shorted to `10.1109/5.771073` by omitting the `doi:` part).

There is only one registration authority, the DOI Foundation, As stated on https://www.doi.org:

> The DOI Foundation is a not-for-profit organization. We govern the Digital Object Identifier (DOI) system on behalf of the agencies who manage DOI registries and provide services to their respective communities. We are the registration authority for the ISO standard (ISO 26324) for the DOI system and we are governed by our Registration Agencies.

You can look up any DOI on their system, like this: http://doi.org/10.1109/5.771073 which will resolve the name and redirect you to the publisher's current location for this item.

So: **to check that a DOI is valid, it should be of the form `10.numbers/suffix` *and* it should resolve on https://doi.org**

---

In your case, you can see how this is not actually a DOI, but a fake identifier:

[image: screenshot from the original website, showing fake DOI]

The supposed DOI is a URL, but the domain is `doi.one` (not `doi.org`). If you visit the `doi.one` webpage, there is a typo in the first sentence:

> DOI.ONE System Provides a Digital Network for Research Artical *[sic]* and Digital Objects

Comment: " it should be of the form 10.numbers/suffix and it should resolve on https://doi.org" doesn't resolving on https://doi.org suffice?

Comment: Technically, http://doi.org/10.5555/12345678 has the right form and resolves correctly, but is considered a [fake DOI](https://www.crossref.org/blog/doi-like-strings-and-fake-dois/) by Crossref. (5555 is a test prefix.)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I mean, it still provides a heuristic if you're not online, or doi.org goes down for some reason. I didn't know it had to start with `10.`.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- true but the heuristic isn't sufficient to check the legitimacy in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

> What defines legitimacy of a DOI

Check the DOI on https://dx.doi.org/

[image]