# My DOI was changed from fake to real

Tags: publications, journals, doi

In continuation to [What defines legitimacy of a DOI](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/199136/174107)

My paper was assigned a fake DOI, but they changed it to https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.8150058 which has the doi.org as the prefix.

Is it allowed and is the new DOI legit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That appears to be a legit DOI for a Zenodo deposit. Adding a legit DOI after initial publication is allowed, of course. (Otherwise papers published prior to 2000 could not have DOIs.)

But that doesn't change the fact that you published in a predatory journal. No self-respecting journal would upload your paper to a general-purpose open repository only to get a DOI; they would register the DOI themselves and have it point to their own website.

Comment: Not all self-respecting journals even have websites, mind. Limiting your scope to just major journals, sure, but smaller journals in more niche subjects do not necessarily. Many of those (and even some larger ones) use their publishers’ websites as landing pages, or indeed those of online repositories like (C)LOCKSS or similar.